# Access VBA not finding Excel files on server when using Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hello I am getting a 1004 error when trying to run my code via the task scheduler.  I can run the macro that executes the code directly from Access and it works fine but when running from Task Scheduler it will not find the file path and error handler kicks in and emails me.  Any thoughts as to how to fix this?  The reason for opening each of these excel files is to run their VBA which updates them to text only from another excel file that contains a lot of complex formulas.  Linking to the excel file that had all of the formulas proved too slow.

Here is the code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Public Function UpdateData()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim mail As CDO.Message
    Dim config As CDO.Configuration

    On Error GoTo 100

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlApp
        .Application.Visible = False
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\CV1Data.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("CV1Data.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\CV2Data.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("CV2Data.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\CV3Data.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("CV3Data.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\CV4Data.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("CV4Data.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\602Data.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("602Data.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\PVGData.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("PVGData.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\PV24Data.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("PV24Data.xlsm").Save
        .Workbooks.Open "V:\DHP\Boards\Access Data\ReasonCodes.xlsm"
        .Workbooks("ReasonCodes.xlsm").Save
    End With

    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlApp = Nothing

    Application.SetOption "Auto compact", True
    Application.Quit
    Exit Function

100:

    Set mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    config.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod).Value = cdoSendUsingPort
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPServer).Value = "mr.domain.com"
    config.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort).Value = 25
    config.Fields.Update

    Set mail.Configuration = config

    With mail
        .To = "First.Last@Domain.com"
        .From = "First.Last@Domain.com"
        .Subject = "Error Occured - Error Number " & Err.Number
        .TextBody = "DHPTables Database -" & Err.Description
        .Send
    End With

    Set config = Nothing
    Set mail = Nothing

    Application.SetOption "Auto compact", True
    Application.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: Does the job run as `System` or with a specific user (have you entered a password for the job?) If it runs as `System`, you don't have access to network resources

Comment: How exactly do you run it from the Task Scheduler?

Comment: @FunThomas I run it from a user and I have to enter the password when I save the task.  I can see it open the db but as I said it goes to the error handler.

Comment: unfortunately I am not the network admin so I am running it from a user workstation.

Comment: Is it possible that the network drive is not mapped to V for this user? Maybe try to use the UNC path to access the file.

Comment: @FunThomas I looked in the history and it shows that it is running from User: System.  So if I don't have access to network resources when running as System how do I change it so it has access to the network resources?

Comment: @VincentG I mapped the drive myself and it is mapped as V:

Comment: @VincentG I also tried removing the V from the code and having it as "\\10.10.5.100\shared\DHP\Boards....." and when I did that it said Error 1004 Microsoft Excel cannot access the file.

Comment: @DrewBerger: On the "General" tab of the task properties, you define the user account. Press button "Change User" to define it. If you click "*run wether user is logged on or not*", you may not check "*Do not store password*"

Comment: @FunThomas I had it set to run as the current computer username and had the "Do not store password" box unchecked.  If I need to change the user I guess im not sure how to do that.  I did click the change user button but had no clue what to do from there.  The user that is set does have access to all necessary drives because as I said the VBA works flawlessly when running directly from an open session of Access.

Comment: @VincentG do you have any other suggestions?  I have been looking for a while online and can not find anything relevant.  The Access file is located on the C drive of the computer running the Task.  The code in that file I have changed to the UNC path and still it will not open the excel files.  As I said it works fine from Access just not when Access is started by the Task Scheduler.

Comment: I found on Microsoft's site that this is not possible for Office products with the "Run whether user is logged on or not" checked.  The only way to do this is to leave the user logged on constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I found on Microsoft's site that this is not possible for Office products with the "Run whether user is logged on or not" checked.  The only way to do this is to leave the user logged on constantly.  See the reply from Mark Burns.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7d81395f-fc98-4e96-90e0-1331cb4dab3d/scheduled-macro-only-runs-if-user-is-logged-in-windows-server-2003r2?forum=accessdev